# (Android) What is RecyclerView.State and how would one use it with smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, state, position)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview, smooth-scrolling

This issue is probably really simple but I can't possibly be the only one totally confused and it's driving me crazy.  My question is very simple: what is RecyclerView.State and how can I use this with the method smoothScrollToPosition.  I've seen threads where people that used smoothScrollToPosition did not need State, but it [the method smoothScrollToPosition] appears to only work with 3 arguments (RecyclerView, RecyclerView.State, and position).  The first and last arguments are easy, but what the heck is RecyclerView.State???  Is there a way around this, what should I be putting in that field?

One way around this that I already know of is to initialize a smoothScroller by itself, but I can't do that with my custom layoutManager because it changes the method smoothScrollToPosition only and wouldn't be affected by a separate smoothScroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call smoothScrollToPosition at LayoutManager. Try to call at your RecyclerView object.

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(5); // Scroll to 5 item
```

Docs - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Comment: Ok yup!  That was the problem, everything's fixed now.  It's tempting to save face and delete the question but I'll leave it :D.  Also another way around I just realized DOES involve editing the LayoutManager, by overriding some methods in the class that extends LinearSmoothScroller.  Thanks a lot!